# Shifting long vectors between AVX registers (on pre AVX512VL CPUs)

Tags: assembly, rotation, intrinsics, avx, shift

I in the process of making some 2D/planar image data resampler and current highest performance approach of 2D convolution need to perform shift of long float32 vector between AVX (ymm or zmm) registers at fixed number of float32 (4 byte) values. The shift distance is equal to multiplication ratio of image enlargment, so for integer ratio I need to shift to 2,3,4,5,6 float32 in between long number of AVX registers. The shifting on 8 and 16 is just a renaming of registers.

The fastest current code for shift to 4 float32 uses rare AVX instruction

_mm256_permute2f128_ps. It allow to shift and exchange data between 2 ymm registers.

So current shift to 4 float32 in between 7 ymm registers looks like

```
_mm_store_ps(pfProc, _mm256_castps256_ps128(my_ymm0));
my_ymm0 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(my_ymm0, my_ymm1, 33);
my_ymm1 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(my_ymm1, my_ymm2, 33);
my_ymm2 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(my_ymm2, my_ymm3, 33);
my_ymm3 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(my_ymm3, my_ymm4, 33);
my_ymm4 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(my_ymm4, my_ymm5, 33);
my_ymm5 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(my_ymm5, my_ymm6, 33);
my_ymm6 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(my_ymm6, my_ymm6, 49);
my_ymm6 = _mm256_insertf128_ps(my_ymm6, *(__m128*)(pfProc + 56), 1);
```

with storing out 4 float result at first, shift and load 4 float to the end. With a large number of fma instructions this multi-sample convolution approach reach about 30..35% of theoretical FMA performance of 4 core intel 9th generation CPU with 4 FMA512 units.

Unfortunately I can not found 1 instruction to make shift to other number of floats in the instruction sets before AVX512VL.

Currently found approach on before_AVX512VL for shifting to 2 floats uses permute for shift inside ymm and blend to transfer shifted-out number of floats to another ymm:

```
const register __m256i my_ymm8_main_circ = _mm256_set_epi32(1, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2); // main circulating const

my_ymm2 = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(my_ymm2, my_ymm8_main_circ); // circulate by 2 ps to the left
my_ymm3 = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(my_ymm3, my_ymm8_main_circ); // circulate by 2 ps to the left
my_ymm2 = _mm256_blend_ps(my_ymm2, my_ymm3, 192); // copy higher 2 floats

my_ymm4 = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(my_ymm4, my_ymm8_main_circ); // circulate by 2 ps to the left
my_ymm3 = _mm256_blend_ps(my_ymm3, my_ymm4, 192); // copy higher 2 floats

my_ymm5 = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(my_ymm5, my_ymm8_main_circ); // circulate by 2 ps to the left
my_ymm4 = _mm256_blend_ps(my_ymm4, my_ymm5, 192); // copy higher 2 floats

my_ymm6 = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(my_ymm6, my_ymm8_main_circ); // circulate by 2 ps to the left
my_ymm5 = _mm256_blend_ps(my_ymm5, my_ymm6, 192); // copy higher 2 floats

my_ymm7 = _mm256_permutevar8x32_ps(my_ymm7, my_ymm8_main_circ); // circulate by 2 ps to the left
my_ymm6 = _mm256_blend_ps(my_ymm6, my_ymm7, 192); // copy higher 2 floats
```

It works visibly slower and uses very large immediate (sized as large as ymm 256 bit register) to set only a few control bits for permutation. That do not allow do use more ymm regs for data storing and cause compiler to load/store immediate and slow down execution.

The other approach is to store (to L1d cache) the long vector from 5..7 ymm regs and load back with shifted address. But it looks even slower because of large buck memory read-write operation and I can not be sure if it will not be transfered via all cache hierarchy causing memory controller to slow down the main memory load/store streams in multi core CPU.

With AVX512VL instruction set I see the 2-sources permutation instruction

`_mm512_permutex2var_ps` (also uses large zmm immediate to select float32 for permutation).

It can replace `_mm256_permute2f128_ps` for any number of float32 taken from 1 and from 2nd  zmm registers so allow to shift to any number of float32 between registers in 1 instruction.

But AVX512VL CPUs are not in common use at endusers in even 2021. May be in 10 years later will. But not now.

May be other approaches exist for non-AVX512VL capable CPUs for faster shift of float32 long vectors beween a number of ymm (and may be zmm) registers at any step measured in ps floats ?

I got several questions about the whole implemented algorithm using this long vector shift. One of the most short 2D/planar upsizer to 4x function listing is:

```
void JincResize::KernelRowAll_avx2_mul4_taps4_cb(unsigned char* src, int iSrcStride, int iInpWidth, int iInpHeight, unsigned char* dst, int iDstStride, const int ciMul, const int ciTaps, const int ciKS)
{
    // current input plane sizes
    iWidthEl = iInpWidth + 64/*2 * iKernelSize*/;
    iHeightEl = iInpHeight + 64/*2 * iKernelSize*/;

    const int k_col8 = 32/*iKernelSize*/ - (32/*iKernelSize*/ % 8);
    const int col8 = iWidthEl - 4/*iTaps*/ - ((iWidthEl - 4/*iTaps*/) % 8);
    float* pfCurrKernel = g_pfKernel;

    int64_t col;

    memset(pfFilteredCirculatingBuf, 0, iWidthEl * 32 * 4/*iKernelSize * iMul*/ * sizeof(float));

// no MT version 
    for (int64_t row = 4/*iTaps*/; row < iHeightEl - 4/*iTaps*/; row++) // input lines counter
    {
        // start all row-only dependent ptrs here 
        float* pfInpRowSamplesFloatBufStart = pfInpFloatRow; 
        GetInpElRowAsFloat_avx2(row, iInpHeight, iInpWidth, src, iSrcStride, pfInpRowSamplesFloatBufStart, 32/*iKernelSize*/);

        for (col = 4/*iTaps*/; col < col8; col += 8) // input cols counter
        {
            float* pfColStart = pfInpRowSamplesFloatBufStart + col;

            float* pfCurrKernel_pos = pfCurrKernel;

            for (int64_t k_row = 0; k_row < iKernelSize; k_row++)
            {
                float* pfProc = vpfRowsPointers[k_row] + col * 4/*iMul*/;

                __m256 my_ymm0, my_ymm1, my_ymm2, my_ymm3, my_ymm4, my_ymm5, my_ymm6, my_ymm7; // out samples
                __m256 my_ymm8, my_ymm9, my_ymm10, my_ymm11; // inp samples
                __m256 my_ymm12, my_ymm13, my_ymm14, my_ymm15; // kernel samples

                my_ymm12 = _mm256_load_ps(pfCurrKernel_pos);
                my_ymm13 = _mm256_load_ps(pfCurrKernel_pos + 8);
                my_ymm14 = _mm256_load_ps(pfCurrKernel_pos + 16);
                my_ymm15 = _mm256_load_ps(pfCurrKernel_pos + 24);

                my_ymm0 = _mm256_load_ps(pfProc);
                my_ymm1 = _mm256_load_ps(pfProc + 8);
                my_ymm2 = _mm256_load_ps(pfProc + 16);
                my_ymm3 = _mm256_load_ps(pfProc + 24);
                my_ymm4 = _mm256_load_ps(pfProc + 32);
                my_ymm5 = _mm256_load_ps(pfProc + 40);
                my_ymm6 = _mm256_load_ps(pfProc + 48);

                my_ymm8 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(pfColStart + 0); // 1
                my_ymm9 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(pfColStart + 2); // 3
                my_ymm10 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(pfColStart + 4); // 5
                my_ymm11 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(pfColStart + 6); // 7 

                    // 1st sample
                my_ymm0 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm12, my_ymm8, my_ymm0);
                my_ymm1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm13, my_ymm8, my_ymm1);
                my_ymm2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm14, my_ymm8, my_ymm2);
                my_ymm3 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm15, my_ymm8, my_ymm3);

                // 3rd sample
                my_ymm1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm12, my_ymm9, my_ymm1);
                my_ymm2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm13, my_ymm9, my_ymm2);
                my_ymm3 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm14, my_ymm9, my_ymm3);
                my_ymm4 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm15, my_ymm9, my_ymm4);

                // 5th sample
                my_ymm2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm12, my_ymm10, my_ymm2);
                my_ymm3 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm13, my_ymm10, my_ymm3);
                my_ymm4 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm14, my_ymm10, my_ymm4);
                my_ymm5 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm15, my_ymm10, my_ymm5);


                // 7th sample
                my_ymm3 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm12, my_ymm11, my_ymm3);
                my_ymm4 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm13, my_ymm11, my_ymm4);
                my_ymm5 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm14, my_ymm11, my_ymm5);
                my_ymm6 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm15, my_ymm11, my_ymm6);


                _mm_store_ps(pfProc, _mm256_castps256_ps128(my_ymm0));
                my_ymm0 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(my_ymm0, my_ymm1, 33);
                my_ymm1 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(my_ymm1, my_ymm2, 33);
                my_ymm2 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(my_ymm2, my_ymm3, 33);
                my_ymm3 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(my_ymm3, my_ymm4, 33);
                my_ymm4 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(my_ymm4, my_ymm5, 33);
                my_ymm5 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(my_ymm5, my_ymm6, 33);
                my_ymm6 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(my_ymm6, my_ymm6, 49);
                my_ymm6 = _mm256_insertf128_ps(my_ymm6, *(__m128*)(pfProc + 56), 1);

                // even samples
                my_ymm8 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(pfColStart + 1); // 2
                my_ymm9 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(pfColStart + 3); // 4
                my_ymm10 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(pfColStart + 5); // 6
                my_ymm11 = _mm256_broadcast_ss(pfColStart + 7); // 8 

                    // 2nd sample
                my_ymm0 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm12, my_ymm8, my_ymm0);
                my_ymm1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm13, my_ymm8, my_ymm1);
                my_ymm2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm14, my_ymm8, my_ymm2);
                my_ymm3 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm15, my_ymm8, my_ymm3);

                // 4th sample
                my_ymm1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm12, my_ymm9, my_ymm1);
                my_ymm2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm13, my_ymm9, my_ymm2);
                my_ymm3 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm14, my_ymm9, my_ymm3);
                my_ymm4 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm15, my_ymm9, my_ymm4);

                // 6th sample
                my_ymm2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm12, my_ymm10, my_ymm2);
                my_ymm3 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm13, my_ymm10, my_ymm3);
                my_ymm4 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm14, my_ymm10, my_ymm4);
                my_ymm5 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm15, my_ymm10, my_ymm5);

                // 7th sample
                my_ymm3 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm12, my_ymm11, my_ymm3);
                my_ymm4 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm13, my_ymm11, my_ymm4);
                my_ymm5 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm14, my_ymm11, my_ymm5);
                my_ymm6 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(my_ymm15, my_ymm11, my_ymm6);

                _mm256_store_ps(pfProc + 4, my_ymm0);
                _mm256_store_ps(pfProc + 12, my_ymm1);
                _mm256_store_ps(pfProc + 20, my_ymm2);
                _mm256_store_ps(pfProc + 28, my_ymm3);
                _mm256_store_ps(pfProc + 36, my_ymm4);
                _mm256_store_ps(pfProc + 44, my_ymm5);
                _mm256_store_ps(pfProc + 52, my_ymm6);

                pfCurrKernel_pos += 32/*iKernelSize*/; // point to next kernel row now
            } // k_row
 
        } // col

        // need to process last up to 7 cols separately...
        for (col = col8 + 4/*iTaps*/; col < iWidthEl - 4/*iTaps*/; col++) // input cols counter
        {
            float* pfCurrKernel_pos = pfCurrKernel;
            float* pfProc;

            for (int64_t k_row = 0; k_row < 32/*iKernelSize*/; k_row++)
            {
                pfProc = vpfRowsPointers[k_row] + col * 4/*iMul*/;
                for (int64_t k_col = 0; k_col < k_col8; k_col += 8)
                {
                    *(__m256*)(pfProc + k_col) = _mm256_fmadd_ps(*(__m256*)(pfCurrKernel_pos + k_col), _mm256_broadcast_ss(&pfInpRowSamplesFloatBufStart[col]), *(__m256*)(pfProc + k_col));
                }

                // need to process last (up to 7) floats separately..
                for (int64_t k_col = k_col8; k_col < 32/*iKernelSize*/; ++k_col)
                {
                    pfProc[k_col] += (pfCurrKernel_pos[k_col] * pfInpRowSamplesFloatBufStart[col]);
                }
                pfCurrKernel_pos += 32/*iKernelSize*/; // point to next kernel row now
            } // k_row

        } // col

        int iOutStartRow = (row - (4 + 32/*iTaps + iKernelSize*/)) * 4/*iMul*/;
        //iMul rows ready - output result, skip iKernelSize+iTaps rows from beginning
        if (iOutStartRow >= 0 && iOutStartRow < (iInpHeight) * 4/*iMul*/)
        {
            ConvertiMulRowsToInt_avx2(vpfRowsPointers, iInpWidth, iOutStartRow, dst, iDstStride);
        }
        
        // circulate pointers to iMul rows upper
        std::rotate(vpfRowsPointers.begin(), vpfRowsPointers.begin() + 4/*iMul*/, vpfRowsPointers.end());
        
        // clear last iMul rows
        for (int i = 32 - 4/*iKernelSize - iMul*/; i < 32/*iKernelSize*/; i++)
        {
            memset(vpfRowsPointers[i], 0, iWidthEl * 4/*iMul*/ * sizeof(float));
        } 
    } // row
}
```

As asked adding completely non-vectorized C-version of resampler:

```
void JincResize::KernelRowAll_c_mul_cb(unsigned char *src, int iSrcStride, int iInpWidth, int iInpHeight, unsigned char *dst, int iDstStride)
{
    iWidthEl = iInpWidth + 2 * iKernelSize;
    iHeightEl = iInpHeight + 2 * iKernelSize;
        
    float* pfCurrKernel = g_pfKernel;

 
    memset(pfFilteredCirculatingBuf, 0, iWidthEl * iKernelSize * iMul * num_threads * sizeof(float));

// single threaded for now
    for (int64_t row = iTaps; row < iHeightEl - iTaps; row++) // input lines counter
    {

        float* pfInpRowSamplesFloatBufStart = pfInpFloatRow; 
        (this->*GetInpElRowAsFloat)(row, iInpHeight, iInpWidth, src, iSrcStride, pfInpRowSamplesFloatBufStart);

        for (int64_t col = iTaps; col < iWidthEl - iTaps; col++) // input cols counter
        {
            float fInpSample = pfInpRowSamplesFloatBufStart[col];
            float* pfCurrKernel_pos = pfCurrKernel;
            float* pfProc;

            for (int64_t k_row = 0; k_row < iKernelSize; k_row++)
            {
                pfProc = vpfRowsPointers[k_row] + col * iMul;
                for (int64_t k_col = 0; k_col < iKernelSize; k_col++)
                {
                    pfProc[k_col] += pfCurrKernel_pos[k_col] * fInpSample;
                } // k_col 
                pfCurrKernel_pos += iKernelSize; // point to next kernel row now
            } // k_row

        } // col

        int iOutStartRow = (row - (iTaps + iKernelSize))*iMul;
        //iMul rows ready - output result, skip iKernelSize+iTaps rows from beginning
        if (iOutStartRow >= 0 && iOutStartRow < (iInpHeight)*iMul)
        {
            ConvertNRowsToInt_c(vpfRowsPointers, iInpWidth, iOutStartRow, dst, iDstStride, iMul);
        }

        // circulate pointers to iMul rows upper
        std::rotate(vpfRowsPointers.begin(), vpfRowsPointers.begin() + iMul, vpfRowsPointers.end());

        // clear last iMul rows
        for (int i = iKernelSize - iMul; i < iKernelSize; i++)
        {
            memset(vpfRowsPointers[i], 0, iWidthEl*iMul * sizeof(float));
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you benchmark that storing and storing and (shifted) reloading is slower, or what do you mean by "it looks even slower"? Generally, the best solution will depend on the context (how many other instructions happen, how much register pressure do you have ...)

Comment: If you (or OoO exec) can hide the latency, store/reload is definitely worth considering.  Especially when you have this much data, the slow store-forwarding can be "pipelined".  Although your shuffle+blend per result (plus one extra at the start) is pretty good; blend is quite cheap and there isn't a long dep chain.  IDK if it could be useful to use `vshufps ymm,ymm,ymm, imm8` (in-lane 2-source shuffle with some limits on which source each element can come from); https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/shufps

Comment: Note that for rotating by an even number of floats, you can shuffle with 64-bit granularity using [`vpermpd y,y, imm8`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermpd) (immediate control instead of needing to load a `my_ymm8_main_circ` vector constant).

Comment: Have you considered shifting the kernels instead? (or care to share the overall algorithm for alternative approaches?)

Comment: "Did you benchmark that storing and storing and (shifted) reloading is slower, or what do you mean by "it looks even slower"? " - Yes. The store and shifted load cause significant slow-down. Also the application looks already very limited by memory traffic (do not know why - may be still bad optimization to architecture) so moving from 4 to 8..12+ threads (with real cores) gives very small gain to speed. Although the FMA performance increases linearly.

Comment: "Have you considered shifting the kernels instead?" - It is also in the plan for testing, but it will use more ymm registers because of storing small parts of shifted kernel rows. Also waists FMA ops for many zero members of kernels. Currently kernel rows well fits ymm for 4x and 2x resampling with taps=4. Non shifted 32 samples kernel fits 4 ymm, and shifted will require 5 ymm. May be it will be separate functions for upsizing required 3,5,6,7 shift.

Comment: "for rotating by an even number of floats, you can shuffle with 64-bit granularity using vpermpd y,y, imm8" - Thank for idea. It will help for shifting to 2 and may be to 6 floats. With possibly faster execution and less storage for large immediate. It is sadly no 'rotation' instructions exist for float granularity (possibly untill AVX512+) with small immediate ? I found at stackoverflow about XOP instruction sets with 2 source permutations and rotations but they are not in common use and was deprecated ?

Comment: If you could re-arrange your data as `ymm0=[0,1,2,3, n,n+1,n+2,n+3]` ; `ymm2=[4,5,6,7, n+4,n+5,n+6,n+7]` and so on, you could rotate them using `vpalignr`. Or you could (partially) transpose your input data and just rename registers. You really show very little context of what you actually intend to do.

Comment: "You really show very little context of what you actually intend to do" - I edit the question and add an example of full listing of function using this long shifts. Also other may be seen at github : https://github.com/DTL2020/AviSynth-JincResize/blob/master-1/src/KernelRow_avx2.cpp

Comment: When you reply to someone, use @ and their username so they'll be notified.  (You get notified when people comment under your question, but it doesn't work for others.  e.g. this comment will ping @chtz (who should take a look at your reply.)

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes for notifying. @OP: It would help if you wrote your algorithm first in a non-vectorized version. Also, for the AVX version, please use variable names like `input0`,...,`input7`, `output0`, `kernel0`, etc. And instead of writing `32/*iKernelSize*/` every time just declare a `const int iKernelSize = 32;`, etc.

Comment: @chtz : It it localized version of resampler only for iMul=4, iTaps=4 and so iKernelsize=32. I found using 'global' class members significally slow down execution and can not declare 'const' in class description because they are params set in the resampler init for other mul/taps combinations. And to not forgot what this hardcoded numbers mean I leave as comments. Also I see hardcoded numbers for loops allow compilers to use best possible optimizations. For other mul/taps I made versions of function with function params passed with 'const' assigned instead of setting 'global' class members.

Comment: @chtz: Completely non-vectorized version also available - added to first post. It is significally slower and looks can not be auto-vectorized by compiler. Using manual vectorizing I made faster internal loop ` for (int64_t k_col = 0; k_col < iKernelSize; k_col++) `  and using vector shift add multi-sampled horizontal processing unrolling previous loop ` for (int64_t col = iTaps; col < iWidthEl - iTaps; col++) ` . It works several times faster.

Comment: Are you able to make your example(s) self-contained (as described in [mre])? I.e., remove all irrelevant parts, define constants as global `const int` variables, etc.